# Is there a way in linux to change the resampling when outputting a lower resolution to a bigger monitor?

Tags: linux, resolution, resampling

My monitor is 4k but my graphics card isn't great at handling 4k gaming. I want to be able to switch to 1080p. My issue is that 1080p looks fuzzy. An image displayed in 1080p looks fuzzier than the same image upscaled 200% in 4k.

Comment: You would have to upscale 400% to have a fair comparison.

Comment: @Tetsujin 1920x1080 times 2 in both directions is 3840x2160 which is 4k. Its 200% in each dimension but 400% the number of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the scale and filter in [`xrandr`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html), but keep the resolution at 4k. For instance, my monitor is on DisplayPort-1. This will output a 1080p resolution but upscaled to 4k using nearest neighbor interpolation instead of bilinear.

For some reason, it only works when separated into two commands like this.

```
xrandr --size 3840x2160
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --filter nearest --scale 0.5
```

Comment: Nice self-answered question!